# Set File name in Message header in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to set the file name in the header of the Message. So I placed the header enricher:

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="singleFile" output-channel="fileNameAddedToHeader">
         <int:header name="file-name" ref="fileNameHeaderEnricher" method="enrichHeader"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

The enricher method is:

```
public Message<File> enrichHeader(Message<File> fileMessage) {
    File file = (File) fileMessage.getPayload();
    Message<File> messageOut =
        MessageBuilder.withPayload(fileMessage.getPayload()).copyHeadersIfAbsent(fileMessage.getHeaders())
            .setHeaderIfAbsent("file-name", file.getName()).build();
    return messageOut;
  }
```

But the header doesn't seem to be added properly.

```
.11:32:33.248 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'fileNameAddedToHeader', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/cost1.txt, headers={timestamp=1418363253171, id=d119e90e-938c-89c3-803e-e980da3de2db, correlationId=d2d5bf51-0647-12db-916d-98884943c08b, file-name=GenericMessage [payload=/home/cost1.txt, headers={timestamp=1418363253170, id=2374031d-4cc8-43bc-f15a-8061c28bec51, correlationId=d2d5bf51-0647-12db-916d-98884943c08b, file-name=costcenter1.txt, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=1}], sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=1}]
```

It seems that `file-name` contains the header part instead of file name.

```
file-name=GenericMessage [payload=/home/cost1.txt, headers={timestamp=1418363253170, id=2374031d-4cc8-43bc-f15a-8061c28bec51, correlationId=d2d5bf51-0647-12db-916d-98884943c08b, file-name=costcenter1.txt, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=1}]
```

I am expecting `file-name=cost1.txt` in the header. What am I doing wrong on setting the header? And is this task possible with SpEL to add file-name to header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do that wrong way.

See:

```
<int:header name="file-name" ref="fileNameHeaderEnricher" method="enrichHeader"/>
```

It assumes that the result of that method will be populated to the `file-name` header.

Since your `enrichHeader` returns a `Message` object, we exactly see that in the end.

The SpEL variant looks better for your case:

```
<int:header name="file-name" expression="payload.name"/>
```

Note, if you are going use it for a downstream `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>` the header must be `file_name` - `FileHeaders`.